# mysql join show all records in left table with a flag for matching records in right table

Tags: mysql, join

I need a help from mySQL Join tables which should list all users in 'Table A' and also should show flag by matching records in 'Table B'

```
Table A (users)
=====================
id | name 
=====================
1  | aaa 
2  | bbb 
3  | ccc 
4  | ddd 
5  | eee 



Table B (users_likes) 
=====================
like_by | like_to 
=====================
1       | 2  
1       | 3  
2       | 3  
4       | 1  
5       | 1
```

if user 'aaa'(id:1) login to the system and performs a search to list all users except his details so the results will be

```
2 | bbb 
3 | ccc 
4 | ddd 
5 | eee
```

also he needs to see a flag when listing which shows his 'like_by' 
eg:

```
2 | bbb | (flag:TRUE) 
3 | ccc | (flag:TRUE) 
4 | ddd | flag:false) 
5 | eee | (flag:false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an easy solution for your problem is to use `UNION` and few `SubQuery`(*although other solution may exist other than this*)

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/699a4/1)

```
SELECT  DISTINCT b.id, b.name,'TRUE' AS FLAG
FROM    users_likes a
             INNER JOIN users b
                  on a.like_to = b.id
WHERE   like_by = 1
UNION
SELECT  DISTINCT id, name,'FALSE' AS FLAG
FROM    users
WHERE   ID NOT IN
(
     SELECT  DISTINCT b.id
     FROM    users_likes a
                  INNER JOIN users b
                       on a.like_to = b.id
     WHERE   like_by = 1
)
AND id <> 1
```

or without using `UNION` and much simplier solution is the one below.

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/699a4/12)

```
SELECT  a.id,
        a.name,
        IF(COALESCE(b.like_by, -1) = 1, 'TRUE', 'FALSE') AS `Flag`
FROM    users a
             LEFT JOIN users_Likes b 
                 ON a.id = b.like_to
WHERE    a.ID <> 1
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: Thanks john, i tried the second query, it works fine as expected.. thanks for the timely help... much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,b.like_by IS NOT NULL
FROM users a
LEFT JOIN users_likes b ON (a.id = b.like_to)
GROUP BY a.id
```

This will give all items of 'a' with 1 where there is a like_to to that a and 0 where there isn't.
(You can add WHERE a.id != 1 to exclude user 1).

Edit:
Changing the third column to be true false based on user 1's likes. I originally thought it was any like.

```
SELECT a.id,a.username,b.like_by IS NOT NULL
FROM users a
LEFT JOIN user_likes b ON (a.id = b.like_to AND b.like_by = 1)
WHERE a.id != 1
GROUP BY a.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea34d/10

Comment: Jim, i tried this query it brings all the values from users and also marks as '1' every row, even user.id is equal to users_likes.like_by or not... pls check this link [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea34d/3, any way thanks for trying out...

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select 
B.like_to,
BNames.name,
case when B.like_by = 1 then True else False end
from Table_A A
left outer join Table_B B on A.id = B.like_by
left outer join Table_A BNames on B.like_to = BNames.id
where B.like_to <> 1
```

hope it helps.

Comment: this will now show exact result. especially if a user didn't like a certain user.